# Best practice for having programmatically created UpdatePanel expand to fill parent container?

Tags: c#, css, updatepanel

In doing some reworking of my web application I encountered the following issue:

Although an ASP UpdatePanel does not have a height property it does not automatically expand to fill its parents container. Instead, it grows with its children's dimensions. In my scenario, the child does not have dimensions -- it should expand to fill its parents container. This causes both the UpdatePanel and its child to have very small heights.

Before I had:

[Parent Container] -> [Child Container] with both ParentContainer and ChildContainer's height property unset so that they will fill containers higher up in the hierarchy.

Now I have:

[Parent Container] -> [Update Panel] -> [Child Container]. Parent Container's dimensions are not guaranteed to be non-empty, so I am unable to programatically set ChildContainer's dimensions in all cases. As such, I would like my UpdatePanel to work in the same fashion as the controls it is wrapped around.

Is my best bet to go into the CSS and do something like:

```
.UpdatePanel
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

or do I have other, cleaner options available to me? I am creating these controls server-side, so I don't have the opportunity to wrap them in divs (nor do I want to).

EDIT:

I (can't?) use Panel instead of UpdatePanel because I would like to use the functionality of being able to update conditionally. I have a timer on my page which calls UpdatePanel.Update() on controls -- this functionality does not exist in panel AFAIK.

The body of my page is height: 100% and here is the static structure hierarchy.

The location where RadPane2 is declared is where an UpdatePanel will be slipped in. It needs to be between the RadPane and the CormantRadDockZone controls. This is only the 'base' implementation, however. Users have the ability to stack more RadPane/UpdatePanel/CormantRadDockZone 1:1:1 contents onto the page. As such, I have UpdatePanels being generated dynamically -- which means I can't apply the CSS to just an UpdatePanel's ID.

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter2" runat="server" BorderSize="0" Height="100%" HeightOffset="155" Skin="Web20" Width="100%" PanesBorderSize="0">
    <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane_DefaultExpand" runat="server" CssClass="allRoundedCorners" Scrolling="None">
        <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" Runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server">
                <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" Runat="server" BorderSize="0" Height="100%" Skin="Web20" Width="100%">
                    <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" Runat="server" CssClass="leftRoundedCorners" Scrolling="None" Width="20px">
                        <telerik:RadSlidingZone ID="RadSlidingZone1" Runat="server" ClickToOpen="True" Width="20px">
                            <telerik:RadSlidingPane ID="RadSlidingPane1" Runat="server" BackColor="#ECF4FD" IconUrl="~/Content/Dashboard/Icons/configuration.png" MinWidth="160" Scrolling="Y" TabView="ImageOnly" Title="Configuration" Width="160px" EnableDock="False">
                                <telerik:RadListBox ID="lstBxSettings" runat="server" EnableDragAndDrop="True" onclientdragging="OnClientDragging" ondropped="LstBxSettings_Dropped" Skin="Web20" Width="100%" onclientdropped="OnClientDropped">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Horizontal Bar" Value="Horizontal"/>
                                        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Vertical Bar" Value="Vertical" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadListBox>
                            </telerik:RadSlidingPane>
                            <telerik:RadSlidingPane ID="RadSlidingPane2" Runat="server" IconUrl="~/Content/Dashboard/Icons/chart.png" TabView="ImageOnly" BackColor="#ECF4FD" MinWidth="160" Scrolling="Y" Title="Custom Widgets" Width="160px" EnableDock="False">
                                <telerik:RadListBox ID="lstBxCustom" runat="server" EnableDragAndDrop="True" onclientdragging="OnClientDragging" onclientdropped="OnClientDropped" ondropped="RadListBox_Dropped" Skin="Web20" Sort="Ascending" Width="100%" />
                            </telerik:RadSlidingPane>
                            <telerik:RadSlidingPane ID="RadSlidingPane3" Runat="server" BackColor="#ECF4FD" IconUrl="~/Content/Dashboard/Icons/historical.png" MinWidth="160" Scrolling="Y" TabView="ImageOnly" Title="Historical Widgets" Width="160px" EnableDock="False">
                                <telerik:RadListBox ID="lstBxHistorical" runat="server" EnableDragAndDrop="True" onclientdragging="OnClientDragging" onclientdropped="OnClientDropped" ondropped="RadListBox_Dropped" Skin="Web20" Sort="Ascending" Width="100%" />
                            </telerik:RadSlidingPane>
                            <telerik:RadSlidingPane ID="RadSlidingPane4" Runat="server" IconUrl="~/Content/Dashboard/Icons/settings_global.png" onclientbeforeexpand="ShowDashboardGlobalSettings" TabView="ImageOnly" EnableDock="False" />
                        </telerik:RadSlidingZone>
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                    <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" Runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" CssClass="rightRoundedCorners" Scrolling="None" onclientresized="OnClientResized">
                        <cc1:CormantRadDockZone ID="RadDockZone1" runat="server" /> 
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                </telerik:RadSplitter>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
    </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdatePanel` will translate to a `div` or `span` on client side so as long as you set the css class properly, this should work. Going via CSS is the cleanest approach.

Here's how you can set the css class (if you want to use this in a css file, make sure you've `PerformSubstitution` set to `true`):

```
#<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%> {
    height: 100;    
}
```

Also, based on browser type, you *may* have to reset `margin` and `padding` to `0`.

Make sure that the UpdatePanel's parent has `height` set too.

**Update:** use a Panel to wrap UpdatePanel (not substitute it)

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Noticed `RadPane` has a `CssClass` property so you can just add it there.

```
<telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" Runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" CssClass="rightRoundedCorners myCssClass" Scrolling="None" onclientresized="OnClientResized">
    <cc1:CormantRadDockZone ID="RadDockZone1" runat="server" /> 
</telerik:RadPane>
```

Comment: UpdatePanel's parent's height is unset in code. This leaves it implied as height: auto. Is this going to cause me complications? Only one control on my page, the root control, knows its dimensions. Everything else auto-sizes based on their location in the hierarchy relative to that root control. Calculating every control's dimensions up to the point where this UpdatePanel is would be a task.

Comment: In addition, my update panels are generated dynamically. I am unable to apply CSS to an ID, only to a class of UpdatePanels.

Comment: If everything is unset, then yeah, it should work. Otherwise, you can set `body { height: 100%; }` too.

Comment: Then wrap them in a `asp:Panel` and assign class in  codebehind like `Panel1.CssClass = "myCssClass";`

Comment: Ahh, but I have a timer on my page which is monitoring all the controls and telling them when to refresh. I have my UpdatePanel's UpdateMode set to conditional to support this which is why I'm not using Panel ;) Sorry to keep revealing more information about the problem, I'll edit this into the post.

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly, having a wrapper panel should not cause any problems. Otherwise, can you have a wrapper div inside your update panel?

Comment: Ahh, are you suggesting wrapping the UpdatePanel in a panel? http://www.nikhilk.net/UpdateControls.aspx considering using something like the StyledUpdatePanel code provided here to access the CssStyle. Probably a bit cleaner, even if grabbing 3rd party code isn't always the best idea. :)

Comment: See my update. You can assign it to `RadPane` too. Then you don't need any third party or extra `Panel`.

Comment: Let me take a look at that. It was a design choice a LONG time ago to leave the height unset, but I'm not sure if the reasons are still existing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No go. I set the height of both the RadDockZone and the RadPane to 100%. It continues to hold its size as tiny. Here's a SS of what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/ih7Gy.png